# JavaScript many input control null or not

Tags: javascript, html

I have 350 text inputs in the form. I want to control those for empty or not. I know for one input eg:

```
var ism=document.getElementById('inputtext').value;

if(ism.length==0){
    return false; 
}
```

But I have inputs :

```
<input type="text" name="inputtext[]"/>
```

What I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check all of them I suppose ?

```
var inputs  = document.querySelectorAll('[name="inputtext[]"]'),
    isEmpty = false;

for (var i=inputs.length; i--;) {
    if ( inputs[i].value.length === 0 ) {
        isEmpty = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider the *HTML 5* way; adding the `required` attribute to prevent form submission with empty inputs

```
<input type="text" required />
```

Trying to submit without putting anything in this will cause a message to be shown and submission prevented

---

Any method you choose should still have server-side validation

Comment: Either this ^ or a non-HTML5 javascript form validator plugin like ValidatorJS or Parsley.